# Secure Socket Shell login

Tags: bash, shell, unix, putty

In Putty is there any bash script to log in different password protected server(ssh) and retrieve data to a specific server? Without ftp is there any bash script for this operation?

I mean, if I want to get data from 3 different ssh named server1, server2 and server3 and save the data in server1 then how should I write my bash for this purpose. I don't want to use ftp concept for this operation.

Comment: Sorry, it is completely unclear what you are asking. Please `edit` your question above and add some more details about what it actually is you want to do. What "operation" do you refer to? What do you mean by "different" here?

Answer (score 1):

I think he's asking on how to download data from another machine via SSH instead of reconnecting via FTP/SFTP. It is possible however you need to specifiy the locations of the external machine by its IP address:

`scp username@sshserver:path/to/file.txt /Users/localuser/Desktop/`

This command is to be executed from the local machine. If a password is required, it will be prompted. Write a for loop and input the server variables into the scp command for your script:

`myArray = ("server_1" "server_2" "server_3")
for i in "${myArray[@]}"
do:
    echo $i
done`

**EDIT**

This is the script for connecting to an SSH server:

`#!/usr/bin/expect -f
spawn ssh user@host
match_max 100000
expect "*?assword:*"
send -- "password\r"
send -- "\r"
interact`

Comment: so, how can I loop through my server using password for server1, server2 and server3 ??

Comment: I have a working SSH script on my laptop which I will be able to post later tonight. It took me forever to get the `expect` shell to work. Would be cool if you could mark the answer as correct if you found it helpful :) Just click the little checkmark.